# Objective Flickr Linker Error while running on iOS Simulator

Tags: objective-c, flickr

I am trying to run my project on Device... its working fine.. but when i try to run it on the simulator its giving me a linker error.. I know this is weird.. following is the error

```
Ld /Users/Shwet/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-eriptsksdksmljhiivlfsmjhgrfg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.app/App normal i386
cd /Users/Shwet/Shwet/git/App-iPhone/App
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/Shwet/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-eriptsksdksmljhiivlfsmjhgrfg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Shwet/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-eriptsksdksmljhiivlfsmjhgrfg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/Shwet/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-eriptsksdksmljhiivlfsmjhgrfg/Build/Intermediates/App.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/i386/App.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -all_load -lxml2 -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=40100 -lz /Users/Shwet/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-eriptsksdksmljhiivlfsmjhgrfg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libObjectiveFlickr.a -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -lxml2 -framework QuartzCore -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CFNetwork -framework AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI /Users/Shwet/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-eriptsksdksmljhiivlfsmjhgrfg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libTapkuLibrary.a -framework MapKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework MobileCoreServices /Users/Shwet/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-eriptsksdksmljhiivlfsmjhgrfg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libThree20.a -o /Users/Shwet/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-eriptsksdksmljhiivlfsmjhgrfg/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/App.app/App
```

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_objc_assign_ivar", referenced from:
      -[LFHTTPRequest(PrivateMethods) cleanUp] in libObjectiveFlickr.a(LFHTTPRequest.o)
      -[LFHTTPRequest(PrivateMethods) dealloc] in libObjectiveFlickr.a(LFHTTPRequest.o)
      -[LFHTTPRequest(PrivateMethods) readStreamHasBytesAvailable] in libObjectiveFlickr.a(LFHTTPRequest.o)
      -[LFHTTPRequest(PrivateMethods) readStreamEndEncountered] in libObjectiveFlickr.a(LFHTTPRequest.o)
      -[LFHTTPRequest init] in libObjectiveFlickr.a(LFHTTPRequest.o)
      -[LFHTTPRequest _performMethod:onURL:withData:orWithInputStream:knownContentSize:] in libObjectiveFlickr.a(LFHTTPRequest.o)
      -[LFHTTPRequest getReceivedDataAndDetachFromRequest] in libObjectiveFlickr.a(LFHTTPRequest.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Kindly someone plz help... thanks a lot

Comment: Do you link to an Objective-C runtime library?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `libObjectiveFlickr.a` doesn't support i386 architecture. You can check it with the following command:

```
lipo -info <patth/to/libObjectiveFlickr.a>
```

the output will tell you if it's a *fat* library and which architectures the library supports.

Comment: The output says
input file libObjectiveFlickr.a is not a fat file
Non-fat file: libObjectiveFlickr.a is architecture: i386

it supports the architecture... the app does not run in simulator... but works fine on device